# Transparent background isn't working and rendering the image doesn't work either

Tags: image

So I was just making a blender banner for my friend, and then I changed everything that would normally make it transparent, but it doesn't work. and also I tried rendering it it as an PNG and that won't work either...[image]

Comment: you are looking at the result after it passed the compositor , please include images of the compositor nodes you may be the render result with something that destroys the alpha, some nodes have a checkbox for alpha

Comment: what @root says is right. You can also set the output to 'render result' instead of 'composite'